# Javascript Discount Help Needed

Tags: javascript

I have this Javascript function that the discount applies to either FlavorBlue or FlavorRed. I tried to add the quantities together, but it did not work as expected. The goal was to have a 50% for quantity 2 flavors either blue or red. I have searched this site for help until blue and red in the face... Any insight would be extremely valued. Thanks in advance.

.js file:

```
function ordertotals()
{
var FlavorBluetotal = (order.selectFlavorBlueQuantity.value * 
FlavorBlueprice.value);
document.getElementById('FlavorBluetotal').innerHTML = FlavorBluetotal;
order.FlavorBluetotalvalue.value = FlavorBluetotal;
var FlavorRedtotal = (order.selectFlavorRedQuantity.value * 
FlavorRedprice.value);
document.getElementById('FlavorRedtotal').innerHTML = FlavorRedtotal;
order.FlavorRedtotalvalue.value = FlavorRedtotal;
var FlavorBluecasetotal = (order.selectFlavorBlueCaseQuantity.value * 
FlavorBluecaseprice.value);
document.getElementById('FlavorBluecasetotal').innerHTML = 
FlavorBluecasetotal;
order.FlavorBluecasetotalvalue.value = FlavorBluecasetotal;
// var total = FlavorBluetotal + FlavorRedtotal + FlavorBluecasetotal;
// document.getElementById('ordertotal').innerHTML = total;
// order.ordertotalvalue.value = total;
var totala = 0;
var totalb = 0;
var totalc = 0;
var quantity = (order.selectFlavorBlueQuantity.value + 
order.selectFlavorRedQuantity.value);
// document.getElementById("insert").innerHTML = quantity;
if (order.selectFlavorBlueQuantity.value > 1) {
quantitya = (order.selectFlavorBlueQuantity.value);
var price = 29;
if (quantitya % 2 == 0) {
//calculate here buy one get one half price
real = ((quantitya/2)*price);
half = ((quantitya/2)*(price/2));
totala = (real+half);
} else {
quantitya = (quantitya-1);
real = ((quantitya/2)*price);
half = ((quantitya/2)*price/2);
totala = (real+half+price);
}
} else {
if (order.selectFlavorRedQuantity.value > 1) {
quantityc = (order.selectFlavorRedQuantity.value);
var price = 29;
if (quantityc % 2 == 0) {
//calculate here buy one get one half price
real = ((quantityc/2)*price);
half = ((quantityc/2)*(price/2));
totalc = (real+half);
} else {
quantityc = (quantityc-1);
real = ((quantityc/2)*price);
half = ((quantityc/2)*price/2);
totalc = (real+half+price);
}
}
}
if (order.selectFlavorBlueQuantity.value == 1 && 
order.selectFlavorRedQuantity.value == 1) {
var quantityb = 2;
var price = 29;
if (quantityb % 2 == 0) {
//calculate here buy one get one half price
real = ((quantityb/2)*price);
half = ((quantityb/2)*(price/2));
totalb = (real+half);
} else {
quantityb = (quantityb-1);
real = ((quantityb/2)*price);
half = ((quantityb/2)*price/2);
totalb = (real+half+price);
}
}
// if (order.selectFlavorBlueQuantity.value == 1 || 
order.selectFlavorRedQuantity.value == 1) {
// var quantityd = 1;
// var price = 29;
// totald = (quantityd * price);
// } else {
// }
// total = (totala + totalb + totalc + totald + FlavorBluecasetotal);
total = (totala + totalb + totalc + FlavorBluecasetotal);
document.getElementById('ordertotal').innerHTML = total;
order.ordertotalvalue.value = total;
}
```

php file:

```
//Inventory
echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><u>Select Inventory:</u></td></tr>";
//Quantity Flavor Blue
echo "<tr><td>Quantity of Flavor Blue:</td><td>";
echo "<label>$</label><input type='text' id='FlavorBlueprice' 
name='FlavorBlueprice' maxlength='4' value='$FlavorBlueprice' 
style='width:20px;'>&nbsp;<label>X</label>&nbsp;";
echo "<input type='text' id='selectFlavorBlueQuantity' 
name='selectFlavorBlueQuantity' maxlength='4' 
value='$selectFlavorBlueQuantity' onchange='ordertotals();' 
style='width:20px;'>";
echo "</select><label id='asterisk'>&nbsp;*</label>";
echo "&nbsp;<label>=</label>&nbsp;<label>$</label><label 
id='FlavorBluetotal'></label>";
echo "</td></tr>";

//Quantity Flavor Red
echo "<tr><td>Quantity of Flavor Red:</td><td>";
echo "<label>$</label><input type='text' id='FlavorRedprice' 
name='FlavorRedprice' maxlength='10' value='$FlavorRedprice'  
style='width:20px;'>&nbsp;<label>X</label>&nbsp;";
echo "<input type='text' id='selectFlavorRedQuantity' 
name='selectFlavorRedQuantity' maxlength='4' 
value='$selectFlavorRedQuantity' onchange='ordertotals();' 
style='width:20px;'>";
echo "</select><label id='asterisk'>&nbsp;*</label>";
echo "&nbsp;<label>=</label>&nbsp;<label>$</label><label 
id='FlavorRedtotal'></label>";
echo "</td></tr>";

//Quantity Flavor Blue
echo "<tr><td>Quantity of Flavor Blue Case:</td><td>";
echo "<label>$</label><input type='text' id='FlavorBluecaseprice' 
name='FlavorBluecaseprice' maxlength='10' value='$FlavorBluecaseprice' 
style='width:20px;'>&nbsp;<label>X</label>&nbsp;";
echo "<input type='text' id='selectFlavorBlueCaseQuantity' 
name='selectFlavorBlueCaseQuantity' maxlength='4' 
value='$selectFlavorBlueCaseQuantity' onchange='ordertotals();' 
style='width:20px;'>";
echo "</select><label id='asterisk'>&nbsp;*</label>";
echo "&nbsp;<label>=</label>&nbsp;<label>$</label><label 
id='FlavorBluecasetotal'></label>";
echo "</td></tr>";

//Total
echo "<tr><td>Total:</td><td><label>$</label><label id='ordertotal'></td>
</tr>";
echo "<tr><td colspan='2'><hr></td></tr>";
```

Comment: Please clarify what your issue is, and only paste the relevant portion of code. Having huge chunks that we have to dig through will discourage people from writing answers.

Answer (score 0):

I was just mistakenly had if else nested inside another. simple fix.